# How to open the "system sound" properly in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have spent about 5 minutes trying to open the "Sound" panel that allows me to configure the system sounds:

[image]

When I go to `Settings/Sound` I do no have any options to manage the systems sounds. Instead of clicking on `Sound` which should be the correct way, I have to enter "System Sound" in the search box and open another hidden weird, bizarre panel also called `Sound`, but this time it is not the same panel.

What is the logic behing this and how can I easily open this panel?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't show the *entire* Settings panel for sound; the image below includes it. You want to click on the "Sound control panel" link in the upper right of the Settings app:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is still trying to figure out how to merge the older, more useful Control Panel into Windows 10's Settings panel.  What you're referring to as a *"hidden, weird, bizarre panel"* is the Sound options via the Control Panel

- In File Explorer:

  - `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items` > Sound - *Sounds* 
     **or**
  - `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound` > Sound - *Sounds* 
     **or**
  - `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound` > Sound > Change system sounds